# Invoke an URL in a new window with Post Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window.open

My application (App A) is built using React and now I have a requirement to load another React application (App B) on a separate window within the same domain on an event in **App A**, let's say onClick of a row. But, the catch here is once after calling the URL of **APP B** I need to send a post request to a specific end point used by that application.

I am using window.open() to load the **App B** from **APP A**.

I have the URL end point and request body. Now, how do I send a post request to that specific URL using window.open, Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: submit a form to a new window

Comment: Hi @epascarello, can you share a code snippet for the same, if possible?